# Move class to another project with all of its dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, dependency-management

I need to transfer a Java class to a new Java project, with all of its dependencies.

Meaning I may have class a, which class b calls it, and class c calls class b, etc.

In this case, I will have to transfer classes a, b and c.

Is there a way to do this for all of the projects?

My problem is that I can't download any files to my computer. I use Intellij as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dependency management tools like Maven or Gradle? A quick Maven tutorial https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

With Maven you can just create a Maven project from your IDE and provide it with a pom.xml that specifies how you wanna build the project and all its dependencies. For each dependency you specify, Maven could transitively pull other dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to transfer all of the classes to the new project. Actually copy them, so I could edit them

Comment: Oh are you talking about the classes you write yourself and external dependencies?

Comment: I'm talking about a class thats inside a huge project that contains large number of classes. I need to transfer one class with all of its inner dependencies inside the project, to a new and different project. I need the ability to edit each and every class, so I have to copy all of them to the new project... :) Just turn a huge project into microservices

Comment: I would assume that project is using some kind of dependency management tools right? It could solve the issue for external dependencies it has. As far as dependencies on the classes within the project, I don't see why you would need to copy individual classes out to a different project if you are refactoring them. Can't you do the refactoring within that project?